# SAMBA Specified Network Name no Longer Available

Tags: windows, samba, yocto

I've got a problem building a SAMBA share between two computers. One is on Windows 8, the other is on a custom Yocto made Linux.
The SAMBA worked before, I don't understand why it does not anymore ...

The error message I get is the following : **"\[IP]\SHARED is not accessible. You might not have permission to use this netwokr resource. Contact the administrator of this server to find out if you have access persmmissions. The specified network name is no longer available"**

I'm `ROOT` on my Yocto

My `SMB.CONF` file (in `/usr/local/samba/lib`) looks like :

```
[global]
workroup = smb
security = share
share modes = yes
log file = /var/log/samba.log.%m

[homes]
comment = Home Directories
browsable = no
read only = no
create mode = 0750

[SHARED]
path = /media/ssd
public = yes
writable = yes
comment = smb share
printable = no
guest ok = yes
```

I've tryed the following :

- Changing the workgroup to `WORKGROUP`
- Start and restart `SMBD` and `NMBD` (with the `-D` option)
- Changing the cable and the interface (I've got two Ethernet entrances)
- Change permissions of the `/media/ssd` file to a maximum with `chmod -R 777`
- Change computer

But still the same problem ...

Would you happen to know what might be going on ?

**[EDIT] : SMB Traces :**

`[1970/01/01 01:09:07.449826,  0] lib/fault.c:372(dump_core)
  dumping core in /usr/local/samba/var/cores/smbd
[1970/01/01 01:09:07.489470,  0] ../lib/util/tdb_wrap.c:65(tdb_wrap_log)
  tdb(/usr/local/samba/var/locks/locking.tdb): expand_file write of 8192 bytes failed (No space left on device)
[1970/01/01 01:09:08.051746,  0] locking/locking.c:905(share_mode_lock_destructor)
  store returned NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL
[1970/01/01 01:09:08.052047,  0] lib/util.c:1117(smb_panic)
  PANIC (pid 4088): could not store share mode entry: NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL
[1970/01/01 01:09:08.053048,  0] lib/util.c:1221(log_stack_trace)
  BACKTRACE: 0 stack frames:`

**[EDIT] : ADD :**

It works on a Linux Virtual Machine, but not on the Windows Host

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was so simple I didn't see it.

This : `tdb(/usr/local/samba/var/locks/locking.tdb): expand_file write of 8192 bytes failed (No space left on device)`

Tells that `No space left on device` is the core of the problem

Liberating some space helped SAMBA do whatever it needs to establish a connexion

Answer (score 8):

Sometimes Samba fails to install or update it's dependencies correctly.

Inspect **/var/log/samba/log.smbd**, looking for anything regarding talloc2 errors.

Try running the following command to ensure all the dependencies are available, this is on Ubuntu, modify for your Linux flavour:

```
apt-get install --reinstall libsmbclient libsmbclient-dev libtevent0 libtalloc2
```

CentOS, RHEL:

```
yum reinstall libsmbclient libsmbclient-dev libtevent0 libtalloc2
```

Comment: whoa!  this is it.  you just saved me a lot of time.  thank you!  +1 (more if I could)

Comment: This solved my issue too on ubuntu 14.04. Thanks!

Comment: You need about 20k rep for this, sorry I can only give you 5!

Comment: After trying every smb.conf example I could find and failing for hours, this was the problem all along. I would never have figured this out, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This can also happen if you happen to try and specify a subdirectory in the share that does not exist.

eg, if you attempt to map x: to \server\share\folder1 but folder1 does not exist, this error message will also appear.

I have no idea why it can't figure out that the share exists, just not the folder and report it correctly, but there you go.

Answer (score 1):

Your environment might only allow SMB2. Try adding the following line to `/etc/samba/smb.conf` in the `[global]` section:

```
protocol = SMB2
```

Then restart samba service via 'service smb restart' and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you setup the samba username and password

```
sudo smbpasswd -a sambauser
```

here username might be your system(Linux) username, ie. sambauser is my linux user,

set the permission of shared folder to sambauser

```
chown -R sambauser:root /media/ssd
```

and restart your SMB server

```
 service smbd restart
```

and then from window machine access your shared folder

go to run by hitting the keys **window key + R**  and access your shared folder

```
\\[IP]\ssd
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. I've forgot to add that i'm ROOT on my Linux, plus my SAMBA security is "SHARE", are you sure I need to set a password, or add a user to the group (since I'm root) ?

Comment: for authentication you always need to have username and password, if you are accessing your data from any remote system

Comment: Ok, so I've done like you did (remplacing "sambauser" by "root"), but it doesn't solve this :(

Comment: Check your samba access log file, it will tell you some information regarding  ,access to file  /var/log/samba/  here it exist

Comment: Alright, I've updated my question with the traces. I'm trying to empty some space since there is a message about it ... but I does not work either ...

Comment: It clearly says that NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL, you haven't setup the proper authentication method do #sudo useradd sambauser #sudo  smbpasswd -a sambauser  #sudo chown sambuser:sambuser /media/ssd

Comment: What would that be?

Answer (score 0):

I also had this exact same error message with a hosts allow line in `smb.conf`

```
        hosts allow = 192.168.0.0/16 172.16.0.0/12 127.0.0.0/8
```

But my client was coming from an IPv6 connection.  So I commented out the line completely and after a smb restart all was well

I could have also enumerated the various source networks that should be allowed to connect.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue for windows 2000 machines and had to enable SMB1

```
/etc/samba/smb.conf

server min protocol = NT1
```

References
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1265923/configuring-20-04-samba-for-smbv1
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-configure-samba-to-use-smbv2-and-disable-smbv1-on-linux-or-unix/